# How to implement is_enum_class type trait?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae, type-traits

How can one implement type trait whose value member is true if and only if the passed in type T is a class enum? While I know that for instance

```
+T{};
```

will work if T is an enum and fail if it is an enum class, I couldn't find a way so far to use this for SFINAE.

Comment: Update the C++ tag to the correct C++ version... This is confusing. is_enum type trait should also work with a class enum. But I also have problems with this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on your `+T{}` test:

#### Option #1:

Expression SFINAE in trailing return type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto test(int) -> decltype((void)+T{}, std::false_type{});

template <typename T>
auto test(...) -> std::true_type;

template <typename T>
using is_enum_class = std::integral_constant<bool, decltype(test<T>(0))::value && std::is_enum<T>::value>;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/babe8cc77dc18703)

#### Option #2:

In *void_t-fashion*:

```
template <typename T, typename V = void>
struct test : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct test<T, decltype((void)+T{})> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
using is_enum_class = std::integral_constant<bool, !test<T>::value && std::is_enum<T>::value>;
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ea16b461467ac51)

Tests:

```
enum class EC { a, b };
enum E { c, d };

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_enum_class<EC>::value, "!");
    static_assert(!is_enum_class<E>::value, "!");
    static_assert(!is_enum_class<int>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: I would love to know the reason for anonymous downvote

Comment: Can't it be done without the template type alias? Just inherit from `std::is_enum<T>` instead of `std::true_type`.

Answer (score 7):

You check whether the enumeration is convertible to `int`.

```
template <class T>
using is_scoped_enum = std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_convertible<T,int>{}
                                                  && std::is_enum<T>{}>;
```

These static assertions will succeed:

```
enum e {};
enum class e2 {};

static_assert( is_scoped_enum<e2>::value, "" );
static_assert( !is_scoped_enum<e>::value, "" );
static_assert( !is_scoped_enum<char>::value, "" );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3ab87f77704a3df).

Comment: I suggest using `std::underlying_type<T>::type` instead of `int`