# Enum-only templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums

Is there any way to ensure that a templated class will fail to compile if a specific template argument is supplied with something other than a strongly-typed enumeration (i.e. enum class)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a trait and `static_assert`.

I.e.

```
template <class T>
using is_scoped_enum = std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_convertible<T, int>{}
                                                  && std::is_enum<T>{}>;

template <typename T>
struct myTemplate
{
   static_assert( is_scoped_enum<T>{}, "Invalid type argument!" );
};
```

<sup>(Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26936868/3647361).)</sup>
[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c34de517227fe32).

Comment: Wow, that is clean. I expected a lot more wizardry to be necessary - thanks! Accepting as soon as the system will let me.