# How can I mimic what the unary + operator is doing to get code to compile properly in gcc-4.6?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, unary-operator

I borrowed a little bit of code from the WebRTC project that I need to get to compile on a system with gcc-4.6. The code compiles no problem on my gcc-4.8 environment. After doing a little bit of digging it looks like the unary + may not be doing the same thing when compiled on gcc-4.6 and gcc-4.8. I say this because the enum test is failing the static asserts as found in the code.

On a later GCC machine the output is:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x test2.cpp -o test2
$ ./test2 
It's equal
It's not equal
```

But on a gcc-4.6 machine the compile throws the static assert errors:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x test2.cpp -o test2                                                                                                                                                                       
test2.cpp:152:3: error: static assertion failed: ""                                                                                                                                                                                          
test2.cpp:153:3: error: static assertion failed: ""                                                                                                                                                                                          
test2.cpp:159:3: error: static assertion failed: ""                                                                                                                                                                                          
test2.cpp:160:3: error: static assertion failed: ""                                                                                                                                                                                          
test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
test2.cpp:195:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eq(int, int)’                                                                                                                                                                     
test2.cpp:195:15: note: candidates are:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
test2.cpp:185:2: note: template<class T1, class T2, typename std::enable_if<(safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T1>::value && safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T2>::value), void>::type* <anonymous> > bool Eq(T1, T2)                                         
test2.cpp:185:2: note: template<class T1, class T2, typename std::enable_if<((! safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T1>::value) || (! safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T2>::value)), void>::type* <anonymous> > bool Eq(T1&&, T2&&)                             
test2.cpp:197:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Ne(int, int)’                                                                                                                                                                     
test2.cpp:197:15: note: candidates are:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
test2.cpp:186:2: note: template<class T1, class T2, typename std::enable_if<(safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T1>::value && safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T2>::value), void>::type* <anonymous> > bool Ne(T1, T2)                                         
test2.cpp:186:2: note: template<class T1, class T2, typename std::enable_if<((! safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T1>::value) || (! safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T2>::value)), void>::type* <anonymous> > bool Ne(T1&&, T2&&)
```

So really the question is, what can I do to get the code to compile for gcc-4.6 while keeping the original intent of the function.

**The part where the code seems to be failing:**

```
    // Determines if the given type is an enum that converts implicitly to
    // an integral type.
    template <typename T>
    struct IsIntEnum {
        private:
            // This overload is used if the type is an enum, and unary plus
            // compiles and turns it into an integral type.
            template <typename X,
                 typename std::enable_if<
                     std::is_enum<X>::value &&
                     std::is_integral<decltype(+std::declval<X>())>::value>::type* =
                     nullptr>
                     static int Test(int);

            // Otherwise, this overload is used.
            template <typename>
                static char Test(...);

        public:
            static constexpr bool value =
                std::is_same<decltype(Test<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(0)),
                int>::value;
    };

// Determines if the given type is integral, or an enum that
// converts implicitly to an integral type.
template <typename T>
    struct IsIntlike {
        private:
            typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type X;

        public:
            static constexpr bool value =
                std::is_integral<X>::value || IsIntEnum<X>::value;
    };

namespace test_enum_intlike {

    enum E1 { e1 };
    enum { e2 };
    enum class E3 { e3 };
    struct S {};

    static_assert(IsIntEnum<E1>::value, "");
    static_assert(IsIntEnum<decltype(e2)>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntEnum<E3>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntEnum<int>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntEnum<float>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntEnum<S>::value, "");

    static_assert(IsIntlike<E1>::value, "");
    static_assert(IsIntlike<decltype(e2)>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntlike<E3>::value, "");
    static_assert(IsIntlike<int>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntlike<float>::value, "");
    static_assert(!IsIntlike<S>::value, "");

}  // test_enum_intlike
```

**The entire minimal example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace safe_cmp_impl {

    template <size_t N>
        struct LargerIntImpl : std::false_type {};
    template <>
        struct LargerIntImpl<sizeof(int8_t)> : std::true_type {
            typedef uint16_t type;
        };
    template <>
        struct LargerIntImpl<sizeof(int16_t)> : std::true_type {
            typedef int32_t type;
        };
    template <>
        struct LargerIntImpl<sizeof(int32_t)> : std::true_type {
            typedef int64_t type;
        };

    // LargerInt<T1, T2>::value is true iff there's a signed type that's larger
    // than T1 (and no larger than the larger of T2 and int*, for performance
    // reasons); and if there is such a type, LargerInt<T1, T2>::type is an alias
    // for it.
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
        struct LargerInt
        : LargerIntImpl<sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2) || sizeof(T1) < sizeof(int*)
          ? sizeof(T1)
          : 0> {};

    template <typename T>
        inline typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type MakeUnsigned(T a) {
            return static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(a);
        }

    // Overload for when both T1 and T2 have the same signedness.
    template <typename Op,
         typename T1,
         typename T2,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T1>::value ==
             std::is_signed<T2>::value>::type* = nullptr>
             inline bool Cmp(T1 a, T2 b) {
                 return Op::Op(a, b);
             }

    // Overload for signed - unsigned comparison that can be promoted to a bigger
    // signed type.
    template <typename Op,
         typename T1,
         typename T2,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T1>::value &&
             std::is_unsigned<T2>::value &&
             LargerInt<T2, T1>::value>::type* = nullptr>
             inline bool Cmp(T1 a, T2 b) {
                 return Op::Op(a, static_cast<typename LargerInt<T2, T1>::type>(b));
             }

    // Overload for unsigned - signed comparison that can be promoted to a bigger
    // signed type.
    template <typename Op,
         typename T1,
         typename T2,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T1>::value &&
             std::is_signed<T2>::value &&
             LargerInt<T1, T2>::value>::type* = nullptr>
             inline bool Cmp(T1 a, T2 b) {
                 return Op::Op(static_cast<typename LargerInt<T1, T2>::type>(a), b);
             }

    // Overload for signed - unsigned comparison that can't be promoted to a bigger
    // signed type.
    template <typename Op,
         typename T1,
         typename T2,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T1>::value &&
             std::is_unsigned<T2>::value &&
             !LargerInt<T2, T1>::value>::type* = nullptr>
             inline bool Cmp(T1 a, T2 b) {
                 return a < 0 ? Op::Op(-1, 0) : Op::Op(safe_cmp_impl::MakeUnsigned(a), b);
             }

    // Overload for unsigned - signed comparison that can't be promoted to a bigger
    // signed type.
    template <typename Op,
         typename T1,
         typename T2,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T1>::value &&
             std::is_signed<T2>::value &&
             !LargerInt<T1, T2>::value>::type* = nullptr>
             inline bool Cmp(T1 a, T2 b) {
                 return b < 0 ? Op::Op(0, -1) : Op::Op(a, safe_cmp_impl::MakeUnsigned(b));
             }

#define RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(name, op)      \
    struct name {                            \
        template <typename T1, typename T2>    \
        static constexpr bool Op(T1 a, T2 b) { \
            return a op b;                       \
        }                                      \
    };
    RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(EqOp, ==)
        RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(NeOp, !=)
        RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(LtOp, <)
        RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(LeOp, <=)
        RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(GtOp, >)
        RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP(GeOp, >=)
#undef RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_OP

        // Determines if the given type is an enum that converts implicitly to
        // an integral type.
        template <typename T>
        struct IsIntEnum {
            private:
                // This overload is used if the type is an enum, and unary plus
                // compiles and turns it into an integral type.
                template <typename X,
                     typename std::enable_if<
                         std::is_enum<X>::value &&
                         std::is_integral<decltype(+std::declval<X>())>::value>::type* =
                         nullptr>
                         static int Test(int);

                // Otherwise, this overload is used.
                template <typename>
                    static char Test(...);

            public:
                static constexpr bool value =
                    std::is_same<decltype(Test<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(0)),
                    int>::value;
        };

    // Determines if the given type is integral, or an enum that
    // converts implicitly to an integral type.
    template <typename T>
        struct IsIntlike {
            private:
                typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type X;

            public:
                static constexpr bool value =
                    std::is_integral<X>::value || IsIntEnum<X>::value;
        };

    namespace test_enum_intlike {

        enum E1 { e1 };
        enum { e2 };
        enum class E3 { e3 };
        struct S {};

        static_assert(IsIntEnum<E1>::value, "");
        static_assert(IsIntEnum<decltype(e2)>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntEnum<E3>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntEnum<int>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntEnum<float>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntEnum<S>::value, "");

        static_assert(IsIntlike<E1>::value, "");
        static_assert(IsIntlike<decltype(e2)>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntlike<E3>::value, "");
        static_assert(IsIntlike<int>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntlike<float>::value, "");
        static_assert(!IsIntlike<S>::value, "");

    }  // test_enum_intlike
}  // namespace safe_cmp_impl

#define RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(name)                                      \
    template <typename T1, typename T2,                                   \
    typename std::enable_if<                                    \
    safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T1>::value &&                  \
    safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T2>::value>::type* = nullptr>  \
    inline bool name(T1 a, T2 b) {                                        \
        /* Unary plus here turns enums into real integral types. */         \
        return safe_cmp_impl::Cmp<safe_cmp_impl::name##Op>(+a, +b);         \
    }                                                                     \
    template <typename T1, typename T2,                                   \
    typename std::enable_if<                                    \
    !safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T1>::value ||                 \
    !safe_cmp_impl::IsIntlike<T2>::value>::type* = nullptr> \
    inline bool name(T1&& a, T2&& b) {                                    \
        return safe_cmp_impl::name##Op::Op(a, b);                           \
    }
    RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(Eq)
    RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(Ne)
    RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(Lt)
    RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(Le)
    RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(Gt)
RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN(Ge)
#undef RTC_SAFECMP_MAKE_FUN

int main()
{
    if( Eq( 1, 1 ) )
        std::cout << "It's equal" << std::endl;
    if( Ne( 1, 2 ) )
        std::cout << "It's not equal" << std::endl;

    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Using macros to create templates looks like something I would stay far away from. A 10-foot pole wouldn't be long enough.

Comment: @BoPersson • although I 100% agree with you (the Preprocessor is the devil!), at least they are being scoped with a cleanup `#undef` on the tail end of the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unary +` trick might be replaced by `std::is_convertible<T, int>::value`.

In addition, the way your write your traits is problematic for gcc 4.6.

Issue is with default template argument.

Turn:

```
template <typename X,
          typename std::enable_if<
              std::is_enum<X>::value
              && std::is_integral<decltype(+std::declval<X>())>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static int Test(int);
```

into

```
template <typename X>
static
typename std::enable_if<
                 std::is_enum<X>::value
                   && std::is_convertible<T, int>::value,
                 int>::type
Test(int);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwnlSCCxTEwC2G7BwAMAEQsBBOQqUrM6rQQCeAB0wB9fU0KCphbW5nZWtizGmIIeTBKqgkwAZj7IRh7eeOkM6gDsfOGhwbaqpaoEmNlMFS6agngAXj4EqgByQYU2Zd0J%2BiLILQAyTMTAmMQAkiwEE9mqIL3oICBJTAyCzZ7OHPk71rIFIV1lFVU1GpodRz1lesT9QyNjk9OzHgwX9U2oSRAKBAAOXwASlM80Wyz6my8eUOJRuPXcXiwSVUIn%2BtAAbL5ylsNHDQgi8vsCcdSqd3tVtlorvCbncHqphqNxlMZtlPo1MD8/tMsSCwQs9EsQFDfFtYcVCUSTlsUap/rIuDikZh8VKyT09urOt0KcxzjTZGZdQiGQMmU9Wa8OVovtzforlQRQcbwcLIfdodtdqaZbjkZhUf9MQAWFV4g4aonaqOdaNlAD0ictLJeBAuABV6KpM1xTMsAG5rETOPCCcpehVJVEEBDjTBgKQVpgJPDAFiYdAB5x16pNivMNMJ0rJ8oIVi52iqCCsbssVCqIfPceTuvOZfjVQ/XNcVRzhXTABUpFUSRIqi8xHPxCMrAkI9UY4MTGELEErp4%2B5Y3bwtfrBgKhWgj9Ag%2B49qezLPGyWY5nmBaihK5bfvuDB4K%2Bj5jjeCoEAAdI%2B%2BpUrUqqREYzjZqeJFRLutLSvSfQWlB1oZn6PQLEx6ZvB8dpcjy2bArUbbfL8eYCTsly5JoQkOhA/GCfaPL/EeoKsTcGgAGLSXxtAqdcMoLOYYI7HwuQkhqBGVJShqaFRZG5rRmrdAoaGdj2pHOB6IB3gA1j4Ijvu2nboFmCGqqoACyTC%2BQAqgFHZdrJ%2B5ib6en%2BgYBBiCwvTVHgyDeMgr4Zq4WzuRCXlRX5cVBSFxqQpG2Czp%2Bj7dNq8asWOADyhbjAwqBMN22EAO71llABGqB1lO37dnmqgTt144edR9TxegnaCII%2BGsYR1m2c4HUeKQzV6iV1EUcdspeKV8HGhd5KnXZnmYJEo0MD4f6fAQIrlt4K3VVo2YIcWyjUvsISpf6nk/X9XZZvmtUgMDpanuNqDcdgdVeHdPSaOksnTkwp6zaNyWkv6CLpZlqgHcsB2zijTWqTGpnme1KZdT1fUDReMPdgAtGiVVdqoaDpCM5aoFlfYtAVY3OB4xCoEYE3C0Q4Gje2zyYSmvM9ltEM7dSNkPfth3Y3tU5HUzl3PWdXBWxDiIm2Vtuve9SSfd9gi/YFsMA7QQMltsXCYtwofW/RXveP5vNw4HIPqCHYfY90HEwQD9tTvHpahVsR4uJYqgsCIDAMB4%2BgOeTpTOQoziozkuMePj%2B5E3uJOShHMqU8QWU0yAdOE9lBC5flhUXBbafTHDRMBwjqqmBAJOM47zPg7Y2vU91xC9f1Z4XjHvv822q0i0rsTEBLUsTjLk6jfLivKxU3Zq62GvAFrbPH0FesWWcRsWwdB2dIbgW3Op3UB9tzbOyei9N6mQPZ2i%2BssH6B9VqwWzsHUOSdO7dCht7WOGcMGJyweHFeCJJ5FU0BRGiCMkZqjnnnAuRcS5lwrrdHBZQa6uXrqoRuzdB7E1JinCmmAMo92ph4WmTc9A5TygVPQ49nYUNgq3XOWNjSNQZjqMhakWZtQhp1LeO9ubEC/sLAWqDv6i3PpfVcN8WBNhaHfS8D8VbP0XK/TW4wN661VPrYBhtiLO0AVAq6Z16ChNtnZPMQC6IgOgUgkArs4EfUQVHAhVDZ4Y0RkHYhycOGlDwdHIWwVCG0NycnbBOiehgDAMojOM8MFqMwPnDQhdi6l3LsQSuVcuF11QGjXheNswt13KoduxlhE3G7llVsFxVDmBcJpPudM%2BY5nMAJBYKzpHJFSOkTI2RliRRiiUzR4zl7AJlK1I4G8Obby5nvUxljzFmO7NY8Wb47Ei1YI48Z98lZuPKB48ZXjumf18VsfxcTAmKLCXZEJ4DnZgOqRA2JjkTpwo8ok5J7tPbIO9s80pmSiGVNIZcokRSMk3WyXQvJVTyUIlqfUzJqjykg2aa02Q7SWFdJ6eTPp4yBkN2GQTVu5yO7VKJDM8ZglFkaQkVIiA5hTxrM2Qq/uTdB6JBSPlfZWR3hHIqrFXmi9gQXLiVcvRNz4xcFkCiWuqgABKmZNDeAAMo2HUtgTQ4UAAK3hwo2AANLYG8B1X1EB3KnlQB4ASWoACslxWLmhaKVYyVcM1lA4Imu6MLiqYstm5O2YIs05ojjI4eyBT7vgqAADwVoKwZdMRkCLbqTdQZbJWlGla2GN4z8SZquZ2hlxJB1joRNmpNENYxkzKM611HqvU%2Bv9YGkNYaI3YAAI6AILm03SI753us9d6v1Abg2hvDRAVomAd21L3XdQ9i6T0rvPeuiAgwCA7ouPui1c6XVHqXae1dF6I2DBvYdWo96I6PuPcus9a7L0AHFP0QdMD%2B9FpQYOAZfQhiNiHwOniCFy9Dch/Lyiw8%2B%2BDIHWY6LHJYUR4wjC1wrH%2BRaqhgB4G6lLJCLYsrPREEYL5aAWBbwICx7IuVCAMDcECu6Y5Jz/EwMAYgawf4RzzcbAtmY%2BU9BTaoCYgg2TYGLoJyZBSFacapCAKZ3QxyZgQMhVARiHnIREBsX8/5ew8ZQvxowp4Dz%2BRGDJ94bmbNJhTNYvAb1ePP0yixlo/wPFZUU8p1Tfiwvkksgaf%2BzsAAaOmq4VtyuoApGKolYpFDi%2BBFwMuQ0ST9XzFx8tstLHSslv7x2FPq97YTom8BuyzKef4GChtTwYVjUrZRMzRAILyF02j16TdHOzdcxBBrlkwJRBzFYnOc13q59zUKMMyg03tArg6itVuQBOUx029AQFwo981YQu2XhEK9XK1mltD2K8JvQmB62mJ4bStptXcHdd%2BlEC4WAlCqlkjN2F5WyoGGVt1bwBgUgGEUPQqhzSF4bOBGizr1cxs0qDgtjrxIKcveAXRhjt5mPVjYxxrjPYgKHgqKlhg0bTGTl83YjevXxhiYVBJ5AUmZMv2S9MJTKmcjpe2lloiiPrrna6/cC0Bm2RoV8hKkd3QLPFgqF917ZX5QW08ij3b6OgwNmxzVbJYVmukimR4d7aFkAm/12aAgsjq3/cB42nIIOuVg9uBDlLcumskskuJfThnpjGYE9Hlr9DZ26LMvo4B7kYhxF7DN7wvnMjTB1z6F3Ed%2BfYGnOmzA1eWZxh0fzmve4Z13X50oV8FZsCyFhKoTAPfW/loYi0N1kp6/l50Zd7wnfhcQC14nkzFwq8jcTvmLgXBnsUt95W6fG1Z/z4IEnkwWgYcMDh5gDfK/uBr8vw3kdU%2BZ/EFm7Ug/R%2Bl%2ByCv%2Bv6/m%2BfeyN3xsJ/CAF/BPQ/RfLQYbVPQjL/dfH/eiP/R/Z/MAV/MAzQJIHeIqMnEGKAm/WA3TbfEeBAoApAkAt/LQN1T/HA6nO6B/PfQAg/UvJfLJIsIObA7/anLfeA2g2begvAXyaHTAWHLYCAC/V0TA5GVfNgu/SnGggAxAngvgrQbvCgyQ9PPAzg2QufEAhg8A0nZgrAiQmA9g3/HfQg4A7XXgnHNAvqDAvQ8Q6/FQ6g/AvKUw4g8whQzQcgyAgw2/VQvYZbcoAvIvf4Bg%2BMUyfwnPWIeIbVPZDIfVD4LPIoW1e1VyCjODYDbwdSaKVoSNKIONYncdSdX%2BKyHLLTHMCBEtfI8mQo7aBJSrWBXFLQSowdaoiGaI3VWIw5EAeQnHQGVPNrTrFo4BNotIDog1LorQiwuOLw%2BuZpNSYdOJdyfhMVCZfIJogY%2BY47RMfOWKILS8ZQCsACXsOLPvEzFjaYRcF8HISPNLLYTaVQI8FMGMDYqVURKmYYvVToxuT4XZdog5MY9yOQOQA6BefgQefgEmAdJ4qdYBPwtYuEyowY6FJXXaJFMopFeGbAeE/0REzUC3bFeo6rRorEodaEuJWpd40YhgZYbo9BPo8SOPMdHE7ockn4kYv4qk8YtwnojE2wzbIPWYpksoRYwGJOEOUZeCUUzEcVdNYkqEu6aVCk9k5YAE21IEyRDVemc5SE%2BEwU0oa5YBVIoDV9TI7IrddDboQ0nDUNE0q9TAc0v9BdWDI0tdG0j9e0zDf9J9NI40rI99O0x8S0qjDI305DdDQM9Im0/DEjW1MjIMJ1T0p0q04M9oBImwf4VQO8BQCAEjFKYBP8CAVQLdAsnMacASd0vAkUNAEQFoGrRo6/CYAgAcPvTdEQNYa/SDRomBdAbiVQ/MtoTAYs08PcMsxwys0QGso0KSesxs5sIuCaZs1sj4dfDsqSLsnsmjYBGZAsxZZ7PYKQQnKkqQeNKQUgFgaQcwE81AaQS4XgfgBIUQcQYOWQWgE8ggc8/cwnbyEAUMXIXCAEcwcweNLgcwW1AATloFyFkFAoBFDEYGkFDBPLPKkAvNICvKkBPMEBAGVTfOQv3NIDgFgCQEizejIAoAgGIvGBAGAFDDDFICSCiwqGIEwsXnfNIA1kiGIDcGkBfNIFFjImmA6hYGk1YqwDvDYDehErwAMAGE42iFYoBwEOrMkCkB4sU0PJQv0CyG4rwuYDYBQH4H4EYH60wsgEJxjWHklkwqkD5mFDaU4FvN4HMFrVUD5mRFYErRcoAHU1gcg%2BYOouAMKHyJA6ADzpBjzTzWK0La0ARMQ%2BYwx2NkAq1QxcJMRcJQwZxcBCALw5AcxNAz4ostwcqBIby%2BBeBXz3yzVSAvzgLcJAKuBaBZBQxQLQLMQuAAQ4KpAEKIrcLULpAMKsLSAcKLzCcCLEAQBxy3cCByBKAKLiA6BSAuwsq5r6BBoVNJEVKdKwrELIrpAcrVB1tJporYr4rgBErVBkrUquqhqPyqqQAlRcJaAfzGqfywx40aLzB6BDyuqkKUK0L%2BrsKKrQqpAArurfq%2BrBrAbSAt56hJZvygA%3D%3D)

Comment: This code was borrowed from WebRTC. You've seemed to have done a magnificent job at fixing it. Why would the original author have elected to write the nullptr code instead of the way you wrote it?

Comment: @MikeyA.Leonetti: The 2 ways should works mostly the same. The first one is generally more readable, the second one is C++03 compatible.

Comment: Workaround to detect enum class done with `std::is_convertible<E, int>::value` thanks to [how-to-implement-is-enum-class-type-trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936640/how-to-implement-is-enum-class-type-trait).